# testdisk - no partition found or selected for recovery

Tags: testdisk

Tried to restore a deleted partition with testdisk. Fortunately when selected the right device the quick analyze function listed the deleted partition. However when I selected the partition by moving cursor down and hit Enter to continue, I got the following error:

```
No partition found or selected for recovery
```

And that was it - so any help how to recover a partition which is listed?

Answer (score 0):

When the partition is selected an action should be dedicated to the recovery - the possible actions is listed on the screen:

```
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
```

And there is a hint also how to select the action:

```
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics
```

By default the action is `Deleted` - `D`, so use `P`, or `L` to recover the partition. After selecting the right action, continue the recovery by pressing Enter.